# How to cast address to address payable in solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, payable

Got address from 3rd-party library:

```
address wallet = rlp[5].toAddress();
```

And wanna transfer some funds to it:

```
wallet.transfer(amount);
```

Got error:

```
TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
        wallet.transfer(amount);
        ^-------------^
```

And casts not works:

```
((address payable)(wallet)).transfer(amount);
```

Answer (score 39):

**Solidity 0.6.x**:

Here is how to cast `address` to `address payable`:

```
address addr = 0x****;
address payable wallet = payable(addr);
```

And contract cast to `address payable`:

```
MyContract addr = MyContract(0x****);
address payable wallet = payable(address(addr));
```

**Solidity 0.5.x**:

Here is how to cast `address` to `address payable`:

```
address addr = 0x****;
address payable wallet = address(uint160(addr));
```

And contract cast to `address payable`:

```
MyContract addr = MyContract(0x****);
address payable wallet = address(uint160(address(addr)));
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. But I don't know why or understand how it works. Seems really janky, is there no other way to do it?

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer, in Solidity 0.6.0, you can now just do `payable(addr)` to convert an address to an address payable. See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/types.html#address.

Comment: All I get is ParserError: Hexadecimal digit missing or invalid.
Sol 0.5.16.

Answer (score 4):

In Solidity ^0.6.0, you can just use `payable(addr)`. Ref: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/types.html#address